# SATA hot swap (AHCI mode), unplug data or power cable first?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, hotswapping

How to hotswap Sata HDDs?
After I choose 'Safely remove hardware' -> 'Eject WDC xxxxx ATA Device' what should I do?
I've read this:
1-For unplugging I should unplug the data cable first then the power cable after a few seconds because:

> that gives it a few seconds to empty its cache/finish any random operations you may have interrupted, before taking the power out.

From what I understand, this is done by choosing 'Safely remove hardware', right?

2- And for plugging I should do the opposite (plug power then data).

Is that correct?

Comment: When you do `Safely eject ...` and you receive the `It is safe to remove...` then Windows has finished any operations on the disk so the caches are already emptied... it shouldn't matter which one you disconnect first. Otherwise what would the point be in Windows telling you it is safe to remove the disk?!

Comment: Are you sure the on drive diskcache is flushed? Or just the disk cache maintained by the OS?

Comment: @Hennes , No, I'm not sure and I was hoping someone could tell me.
[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer#Write_acceleration) says that the 'disk buffer' is controlled only by the disk micro-controller and I think this means that if the Disk reported to the OS that it's finished  before permanently writing data to the platter, this could cause data loss in case of power failure (or unplugging the drive).
but the buffer is usually 64 MiB, how long does it take to flush?
This shouldn't be more than a few seconds, right?

Comment: It should not be much time, but I have heard (**unconfirmed!**) tales of drives reporting that they were done writing data before actually doing anything. This boosts performance at the risk of data loss.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll give it a few seconds before unplugging, just to be on the safe side.